# Conditionally adding a list to another list of the same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have two list like this:

```
List<leveledCharacters> ListCity
List<leveledCharacters> ListCountry
```

The model looks like this:

```
public partial class leveledCharacters
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public int CharacterId { get; set; }
    public Guid GameId { get; set; }
    public string CharacterClass { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add them to my database context like this:

```
 _context.ListCity.AddRange(ListCountry);
```

But I only want to add them them if ListCountry doesn't have any leveledCharacters with a CharacterId that is already in the ListCity list.

So if ListCity has a leveledCharacters object with a CharacterId of 9151, and the ListCountry list also has a leveledCharacters object with a characterID of 9151, then it won't add them.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linq.

If you mean to either add the whole list or add nothing if any of the ids overlap then you could use:

```
if (_context.ListCity.Select(levelc => levelc.CharacterId).Count(cid => ListCountry
    .Select(lc => lc.CharacterId).Contains(cid)) == 0)
        _context.AddRange(ListCountry);
```

Probably:

```
if (_context.ListCity.Select(levelc => levelc.CharacterId)
    .Intersect(ListCountry.Select(lc => lc.CharacterId)).Count() == 0)
```

gives slightly better performance. You might want to test that.

If you want to add all elements from ListCountry whose CharacterId is not in ListCity then you could use:

```
_context.ListCity.AddRange(ListCountry.Where(lc => !_context.ListCity
    .Select(lc => lc.CharacterId).Contains(lc.CharacterId)));
```

Or the slightly more readable version:

```
var exisitingIds = _context.ListCity.Select(levelc => levelc.CharacterId).ToArray();
            
_context.ListCity.AddRange(ListCountry.Where(levelc => !exisitingIds.Contains(levelc.CharacterId)));
```

However if you need more speed consider using for loops.